# Does span(A) < span(B) imply A < B?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A \subseteq B \subseteq V$ for some vector space $V$, we know that $\mathrm{span}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(B) $. We can see that as span of $B$ can make any elements of $A$.

However does the inverse of the statement hold? So if $\operatorname{span}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(B) $, can we say $A \subseteq B$?

Answer (score 6):

No. For example, take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $A = \{(2,0)\}$ and $B = \{(1,0), (0,1)\}$. Since $B$ is a basis for $V$, $\operatorname{span}(B) = V$, so $\operatorname{span}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(B)$. However, $A \not\subset B$.

Comment: If you write \mathrm{span} rather than \operatorname{span} then instead of $\operatorname{span}A$ you'll see $\mathrm{span}A,$ without proper spacing. That doesn't mean just that \operatorname{} adds spaces to its left and right, but rather that it has context-dependent spacing.

Comment: Yes, true. I forgot that here, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

No. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, take $A=\{(1,0)\}$, $B=\{(2,0),(0,1)\}$. Then $\mathrm{Span}\, A=\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathrm{Span}\, B=\mathbb{R}^2$ (so $\mathrm{Span}\, A\subseteq\mathrm{Span}\, B$), but $A\not\subseteq B$, since $(1,0)\notin B$.